# Does broadcasting over UDP repeatedly send its packet, or just once?

Tags: c#, network-programming, udp, broadcast

Using C#, does broadcasting over UDP repeatedly send its packet, or just once?

I've never used this technology before and I want to temporarily broadcast small bit of info (a small one line string) over the LAN. If the receiving end isn't ready will the broadcast repeat itself or was it a one time thing? The code I'm using is from [here](http://blog.eviac.com/2010/12/network-broadcasting-with-c.html). So what I want to start the Broadcaster one one machine and a few minutes later start the receiver and retrieve what the broadcaster sent.

Here is the code

```
using System;  
using System.Net;  
using System.Net.Sockets;  
using System.Text;  
class Broadcst  
{  
  public static void Main()  
  {  
   Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram,  
                ProtocolType.Udp);  
   IPEndPoint iep1 = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, 9050);  
   IPEndPoint iep2 = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.255"), 9050);  
   string hostname = Dns.GetHostName();  
   byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(hostname);  
   sock.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket,SocketOptionName.Broadcast, 1);  
   sock.SendTo(data, iep1);  
   sock.SendTo(data, iep2);  
   sock.Close();  
  }  
}
```

Comment: Imagine what would happen to the network if every broadcast packet was automatically repeated indefinitely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UDP by design only sends a packet once. It has no concept of handshakes (unlike TCP), error correction, or transmission guarantees. You can't even be sure that your data gets to where you send it unless you manually request checksums or something like that.

Wikipedia has a nice section on this: [Reliability and congestion control solutions in UDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol#Reliability_and_congestion_control_solutions).

So, yes, you will need to implement transmission guarantee code if you want reliability. But what if the message from the recipient saying that the data was received is delayed? Well, then you need to implement some kind of timeout. What if the message gets lost? You need to resend the data to the recipient. How do you know if the recipient gets it *this* time? Etc...

If you don't want to do this, then I'd suggest looking into TCP which automatically manages this for you.

Comment: It's quite possible to receive duplicates of a UDP packet.  Loops and physical layer retransmission are common causes.  But these represent failures in the network, and should not be counted on.

Comment: Interesting. Does TCP have a built in mechanism for handling duplicate packets? I would assume so but I'm not sure.

Comment: Never mind; the answer is unsurprisingly yes. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Reliable_transmission

Comment: To use TCP wouldn't I need to know the IP of the computer I'm sending it to? Because in my case that isn't possible.

Comment: You need to know the endpoint address for UDP as well, unless you are broadcasting on a range.

Comment: @SimpleCoder: He uses the word "broadcast" repeatedly in the question, so I think it's safe to say he's not using a unicast destination (which TCP requires).

Comment: @Ben Voigt: I asked because many people still erroneously use the two terms interchangeably.